# Does DynamoDB latency depend on number of items per partition

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, latency

Newbie to DDB here. I've been using a DDB table for a year now. Recently, I made improvements by compressing the payload using gzip (and representing it as a binary in DDB) and storing the new data in another newly created beta table. Overall compression was 3x. I expected the read latency(GetItem) to improve as well as it's less data to be transported over the wire. However, I'm seeing that the read latency has increased from ~ 50ms p99.9 to ~114 ms p99.9. I'm not sure how that happened and was wondering if because of the compression, now I have a lot of rows per partition (which I think is defined as <= 10 GB). I now have 3-4x more rows per partition. So, I'm wondering that once dynamoDb determines the right partition for a partition key, then within the partition how does it find the correct item? Gut feel is that this shouldn't lead to an increase in latency as a simplified representation of the partition can be a giant hashmap so it'd just be a simple lookup. I'd appreciate any help here.

My DDB schema:

partition-key - user-id,dataset-name

range-key - update-timestamp

payload - used to be string, now is compressed/binary.

In my GetItem requests, I specify both partition key and range key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, your change included two unrelated parts: You compressed the payload, and increased the number of items per partition. The first change - the compression - probably has little effect on the p99 latency (it could have a more noticable effect on the **mean** latency - which, according to Little's Law is related to throughput, if your client has fixed concurrency - but I'd expect it to lower, not increase).

Some **guesses** as to what might have increased the p99 latency:

1. More items per partition means that DynamoDB (which uses a B-tree) needs to do more disk reads to find a specific item. Since each disk access has rare delays caused by queueing, this adds to the tail latency.
2. You said that the change caused each partition to hold more items, I guess this means you now have fewer partitions. If you have too few of them, you can start getting unbalanced load on the different DynamoDB partitions, and more contention and latency for specific "hot" partitions.
3. I don't know how you measure your latency. Your client now needs (I guess) to uncompress the returned result, maybe it is now busier, adding queening delays in the client? Can you lower your client's concurrency (how many client threads run in parallel) and see if the high tail latency is an artifact of the server design, or the client's design?

Comment: Hi, I only compressed the payload. The effect of compressing the payload is that each partition (capped at 10 GB as per DDB docs) now holds 3x more entries than before. I agree that 1 and 2 may be likely to happen. But my understanding is that hot partition should ideally not cause latency to go up but availability to drop, no? Also, does DDB use B-tree indexing on partition keys or partition and sort keys combined?